# Android: удалить уведомление из панели уведомлений

Tags: android, kotlin

Имеется некоторое уведомление с 2 кнопками

```
    val notificationIntentCompleteOrder = Intent(context, CloseOrderService::class.java)
    notificationIntentCompleteOrder.putExtra("oid", oid)

    val notificationIntentDetails = Intent(context, MainActivity::class.java)
    notificationIntentDetails.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
    notificationIntentDetails.putExtra("oid", oid)
    notificationIntentDetails.putExtra("action", type)
    notificationIntentDetails.putExtra("fragment", "notificationDetails")

    val pendingIntentDetails = PendingIntent.getActivity(
            context,
            0, notificationIntentDetails,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT
    )
    val pendingIntentClose = PendingIntent.getService(
        context,
        0, notificationIntentCompleteOrder,
        PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT
    )

mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_push)
            .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.resources, R.mipmap.ic_launcher))
            .setTicker(message)
            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(message)
            .setStyle(NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(message))
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX)
            .addAction(R.drawable.ic_delete_white, "Завершить", pendingIntentClose)
            .addAction(R.drawable.ic_archive_white, "Подробности", pendingIntentDetails)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
```

Необходимо при клике на кнопки уведомления, закрывать это уведомление. Но как это сделать?
autoCancel(true) работает на само оповещение, а не на его кнопки

Как я понимаю

```
notificationManager.notify(m, mBuilder.build())
```

m - Id notification
Может тогда его прокидывать вместе в intent, и уже оттуда закрывать по id?

```
notificationManager.cancel(notifyId)
```

Но мне кажется это очень большим костылем

Answer (score 0):

На самом деле предложенный вами вариант является правильным. У каждого уведомления есть свой идентификатор, по которому можно управлять конкретно этим уведомлением. К примеру телеграм хранит уникальный идентификатор для каждого чата, и когда мы прочитываем это сообщение с другого устройства, сервис приложения по этому идентификатору удаляет нотификацию о новом сообщении из этого чата. Таким образом сохранив этот идентификатор нотификации, можно даже через пуш уведомление эту нотификацию убрать.